# Why a moving light source shows as several discrete sources instead of a gradient

Tags: visible-light, vision

I have a device with 4 small leds. Like:

```
•
•
•
•
```

If at dark I move the device I would have expected to see a gradient of continuous light. Like:

```
<-- movement -->
______
______
______
______
```

Instead, what I see is a discrete grid of dots, like if the eye takes discrete snapshots of the whole image at once (not like scan of a digital camera, I perceive that the dots are vertically aligned). Something like:

```
<-- movement -->
• • • • • • • •
• • • • • • • •
• • • • • • • •
• • • • • • • •
```

My question is why the light source is perceived as several discrete sources instead of a light gradient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that LED lights typically pulse rather than give continuos light. This can be because of flickering due to converting AC power into DC, but also dimmer or driver circuits regulating how bright they are by only keeping them lit for a fraction of time (but, in high quality systems, flickering is so fast viewers will not notice). When you move the line you see the flashes of light separated from each other.

Comment: Re, "LED lights typically pulse" Just to be really clear, that is not an inherent property of LEDs. But it is a common way for LED _driver_ circuits to control the apparent brightness of LEDs.